# Why do I get a segfault error (C++ 98)?

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault

I've been working a C++ assignment (I'm a novice). I'm supposed to add instantiated structs with string members to a list alphabetically (not allowed to use sorting mechanisms).

While I've got most of the functionality figured out I'm stuck at this:

```
    void insertWord(vector<word_entry>& v, word_entry& we){

       for(vector<word_entry>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end();++it){

        int determine = it->word.compare(we.word); //**1

         if(determine > 0){ //**2
          v.insert(it, we);
         }
       }
       v.push_back(we);
    }
```

Apologies in advance if the code is unconventionally written. Anyway, what I'm trying to do is to insert the object at the iterator's position - before the object to which the iterator is pointing (**1) if the if-return (**2) returns true.

Any thoughts? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting into the vector causes any existing iterators to be be invalidated. The next time you try to increment the iterator, you have undefined behavior.  To fix this, you can use

```
it = v.insert(it, we);
```

Comment: I've been able to collect enough information to suspect this, but thanks for clarifying it. Any pointers to a workaround?

Comment: it seems to cause some kind of an error, as my terminal line gets reset and stops responding. thanks however, perhaps I might be able to further narrow down my search now.

Comment: @bewildered: I suspect you meant to return after inserting.

Comment: note it is c++11 code, for older standard, vector::insert is void function.